# Move file outside project folder in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to upload a file in a folder outside my project directory.

Folder structure :

```
-destinationFolder
-myProject
 --public
 --src
  ---myFile
```

My code :

```
  const file = req.files.file;

  var dir = path.resolve("../destinationFolder/" + file.name);
  file.mv(dir, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("ok");
    }
  });
```

Here i'm using express-fileupload package to req my file and use mv() method to move my file in the desired destination,and i'm getting this error

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/destinationFolder/catalogue_song_0.mid']
```

If i change my dir variable to :

```
var dir = path.resolve("./public/" + file.name);
```

I'm able to move my file to the public folder
Am i missing something ?

Comment: Are symlinks or bind mounts in play somehow? Or maybe this is inside a docker container? Because it _appears_ as if the folder above the project folder is considered to be `/`. - Another issue could be that maybe the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: My project is inside a docker container indeed

Comment: So I'm assuming you have only the project folder mapped to `/app` as a volume inside the container, but your `destinationFolder` is in fact outside of the volume on your host machine, which can't work. You should map that other folder also into the container as another volume and then use the in-container volume path for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips i'm trying it rigth away !